# How to Configure VBA to open only excel files

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worbook that copy information from differents workbooks.
To open these workbooks I use the code below:

```
Dim nomearq As String
Dim nomearq2 As String
nomearq = Application.GetOpenFilename
Workbooks.Open Filename:=nomearq
nomearq2 = ActiveWorkbook.Name
```

So, I was trying to not allow the macro run if the selected file isn't a excel file:

```
If Not Right(nomearq, 4) = ".xls" Or Right(nomearq, 5) = ".xlsm" Then
    MsgBox "Arquivo incompatível"

       Exit Sub
```

But the xlsm files aren't openning. I can't wondering why.

Comment: What happens if you use: `If Right(nomearq, 4) <> ".xls" And Right(nomearq, 5) <> ".xlsm"`?

Comment: VBA has no way to know you mean that `Not` operator to apply to the entire Boolean expression, because the expression isn't parenthesized. Thus, the `Not` operator only applies to the `= ".xls" comparison. Heed @cybernetic.nomad's advice, and use the `<>` (not equal) operator instead, to reverse the Boolean logic (`Or` -> `And`) and make the code more obviously correct. Rule of thumb, you want to avoid the `Not something = somethingElse` form, and flip it to a positively-worded `something <> somethingElse`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an alternative, you can limit the user to only being able to select Excel files, like so:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim nomearq As Variant

    nomearq = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files, *.xl??")    'This specifies that it can ONLY open Excel files
    If VarType(nomearq) = vbBoolean Then Exit Sub  'Pressed cancel

    With Workbooks.Open(nomearq)
        'do stuff with the workbook here
        MsgBox "opened " & nomearq

        .Close SaveChanges:=False   'Close the opened workbook when you're done with it
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: That filter will exclude `.xlam` though, and `If VarType(nomearq) = vbBoolean Then Exit Sub` would more reliably detect cancellation.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Would need to declare `nomearq` as Variant in that case instead of String, but yeah, that would work too.  And while it's true that it will exclue `.xlam` files, the OP's code shows that it would also filter `.xlam` files.  I suppose for completeness sake, you could change the filter to be `*.xl??` to cover that possibility though.

Comment: Indeed. And `GetOpenFilename` *does* return a `Variant` anyway ;-)

Comment: @tigeravatar The if statement for when cancel is pressed is not working. I think its ocurrying because my excel is in portuguese. I also tried this:

``` 
 If nomearq = "Falso.xlsx." Then Exit Sub 

``` 
I tried "Falso", "Falso.xlsx" in this code too.

But it doesn't worked too

Comment: @JoãoAlves Make sure you're declaring your `nomearq` variable as a `Variant` instead of a `String`

Comment: @tigeravatar oh forget it, i found the error. btw thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with your `Or` logic:

```
If Not Right(nomearq, 4) = ".xls" Or Right(nomearq, 5) = ".xlsm" Then
```

This statement is actually two statements, add parentheses to see what's happening:

```
If (Not Right(nomearq, 4) = ".xls") Or (Right(nomearq, 5) = ".xlsm") Then
```

You can add the appropriate `Not` logic, or, instead of using `Application.GetOpenFilename` you should use `Application.FileDialog` which has parameters that allow you to restrict the file type.

```
Dim fd As FileDialog
Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
With fd
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xls; *.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xlsb", 1
    .FilterIndex = 1
    .Show
    If .SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
        nomearq = .SelectedItems(0)
    End If
End With
```

If you don't want to use `FileDialog`, then you can make your logic a bit more foolproof:

```
Dim extPos as Integer
extPos = InstrRev(nomearq, ".")
If Not Right(nomearq, extPos) Like ".xls*" Then
```

This should handle XlS, XLSM, XLSX, XLSB etc. file extensions.

Comment: myself use`Like ".xls[xmb]"`